# Angular First SQL retrieve key from Database in array 1 : On screen, need to display text from array2 whose keys corresponds to array1 values

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angular, html-table, key-value-store

I am displaying values in HTML, with angular JS code snippets. First SQL is run to get values in array1(users). I need to display text from array2(pageafterlogin), which keys(US_DefaultPage) corresponds to values in array1. Which tags should i use?

Already tried ng-if
Using JOINS in SQL cause the system to be slow.

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="c in users | filter:search | orderBy:['US_UserId']" id="{{c.US_UserId}}" animate-on-change='c.US_UserId + c.US_Name + c.US_Status + c.US_DefaultPage + c.US_DefaultRestoId' ng-animate=" 'animate'">

<td>{{c.US_UserId}}</td>
<td>{{c.US_FirstName}} {{c.US_Name}}</td>
<td>{{c.RE_Name}}</td>
<td *ngFor="#page of pageafterlogin; #page.ST_Description=c.US_DefaultPage.trim()">{{page.ST_Code}}</td>
<td>{{c.US_DefaultPage.trim()}}</td> 

</tr>
</table>
```

Expected (Display Text)
Text1
Text2
Text3

Actual (Display Key)
P1
P2
P3

Comment: How big are the arrays ?

Comment: With thousands of records. But i believe, no matter number of records, it will follow same code logic to display on screen per key value.

Comment: If there are thousands, I wouldn't load them all at once, I would do a paging system or an infinite scroll. Another option would be to search in the second array for every item in array1 using .filter. Also if there are thousands, it shouldn't be that slow to join database side.

Comment: Also, if you have your DB structure right and optimized and its slow to join 2 tables, it would be much slower to do the same thing client side.

Comment: Do you mean to have 2 loops, first loop through array1 then on each record, search for corresponding value in array 2 ?

Comment: yes but I think that would be slower than a database join. Something like this array2.find(obj => obj.id == array1obj.id)